# Reattach Toilet Seat Pin Inside the Hinge

Tags: toilet

The pin inside the toilet seat hinge came out (this is NOT the bolt that attaches the seat to the toilet). The pin screws into the lid and then I can slide it through the flange (piece that bolts to the toilet) and then through the seat. However, I can only do it on one side because you have to screw it in first on that side and then slide everything on. There is no way to get everything on, on the otherside and still be able to tighten the pin. If I tighten the pin on the otherside first then I can’t slide it though the hinge and seat. There is no way to screw the pin in once it’s assembled as the end of the pin is just flat. Do I have to just buy a whole new seat? [image]

Comment: The two outer pieces look different to each other, are they?  Does the pin have a slot cut into the smooth end?

Comment: Have you tried removing the pin, lining up everything and then installing the pin from the right side and tapping it into place with a hammer?

Comment: (a) I'm wondering how it was assembled. Do the pins look like they might have been sheared off at the ends? Is there a cap in the part by the base of the thumb in the photo for access that way? (b) If you had a dremel-type tool, you could cut a slot in the plain ends.

Comment: Cut a slot for a small screw driver on the non-threaded end, using hacksaw. Then you can take a small screw driver and screw it in.

Answer (score 3):

**That is not a screw-in pin.**

[image: pin]

It is just roughened on one end to keep it from sliding out.

Insert from center part, and gently knock it in with hammer.

You can fill the lid hole part with some caulk (before inserting the pin), to prevent it to slide out again.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from my comment after checking my toilet seat. Try removing the pin, lining up everything and then installing the pin from the right side and tapping it into place with a hammer?

Comment: Great minds think alike